# How to hide only the attachments and read email body

Tags: php, email

How to hide only the attachments and read email body and the attachment is read as junk files, i want to read the messages but hide the attachments if present in the mail

[Here is a screenshot of how the attachment is read]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq8Q7.jpg